# Triggering directive from another directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have a directive that already works and there is often more than one on a page, so it uses isolated scope 'state' to decide whether the contents are shown or not.

```
<bdb-slideable state="expanded" duration="0.3">
   ...
   element content
   ...
</bdb-slideable>
```

there are various other elements on the page that act as triggers for the directives, in this case it might be a Documentation tag so I would wrap this with something to handle the click and a span to show the correct up or down caret depending on the state.

```
<div class="toggle" ng-click="expanded=!expanded">
    <h4>Documentation</h4>
    <span class="fa" ng-class="{'fa-caret-down':!expanded,'fa-caret-up':expanded}"></span>
</div>
```

and this all works, buts its adding work and I have to keep track of what state variable i'm using and on bigger pages (or where I pull in templates this is getting messy). Also the elements or collection of elements that need to be wrapped isn't always a  and can be any text or markup.

I was trying to add a directive via attribute to the element that is going to be used as the toggle trigger and it will manage the correct display of the caret and inject all the corresponding classes.

```
<h4 bdb-toggle-slideable="documentation">Documentation</h4>
```

and then add a name attribute to the bdb-slideable that corresponds to the slidable that will be toggled.

```
<bdb-slideable name="documentation" state="expanded" duration="0.3">
```

My original directive exposes 'state' via a isolated scope two way binding,

```
return {
  restrict: 'E',
  scope: { expanded:'=state' },
  ...
     rest of directive
  ... 
};
```

I want somehow in my new directive to find the instance of the bdb-slidable that has the correct name and then get the initial value of 'state' to set up the caret correctly and then on clicks toggle the caret and set the value of 'state' of the bdb-slideable as required.

So I have this directive for the toggle:

```
app.directive('bdbToggleSlideable', function() {

  function getTemplate(tElement, tAttrs) {
    return  '<div class="toggle" ng-transclude>' +
              '<span ng-class="{\'fa fa-caret-down\':!expanded,\'fa fa-caret-up\':expanded}"></span>' +
            '</div>'
  };

  function link(scope, element, attrs, ctrl, transclude) {

    scope.expanded = scope.target.state;    // ???

    element.bind('click', function() {
      scope.expanded = !scope.expanded;

    });
  }

  return {
      restrict: 'A'
    , scope: { target:'=bdbToggleSlideable'}
    , transclude: true
    , link: link
    , template: function (tElement, tAttrs) {
        return getTemplate(tElement, tAttrs);
    }
  }
});
```

So there are at least two things wrong with this.

The output that is generated by the template didn't wrap the H4 with the div and then insert the span (I would like it to generate the same format as my manually wrapped element shown above) it generated this.:

```
<h4 bdb-toggle-slideable="documentation" class="ng-isolate-scope">
  <div class="toggle" ng-transclude="">
    <span class="ng-scope">Test</span>
  </div>
 </h4>
```

and I also get a error of:

```
'TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined'
```

because state.target is undefined and there is no reference to target in the isolated state of the directive even though i defined

```
scope:  { target:'=bdbToggleSlideable' }
```

and this had to have existed in order for the directive to be compiled so I'm assuming that it does know now to find the directive where name="documentation" and so gets undefined as a value.

Does any one have any ideas how to achieve this, or how to get / set the 'state' value on another directive with a name="" attribute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I rewrote the new directive to work like this:

```
app.directive('bdbToggleSlideable', function() {

  function getTemplate(tElement, tAttrs) {
    var state = tAttrs.state;
    return  '<div class="toggle" ng-click="'+state+'=!'+state+'">' +
              '<ng-transclude></ng-transclude>' +
              '<span ng-class="{\'fa fa-caret-down\':!'+state+',\'fa fa-caret-up\':'+state+'}"></span>' +
            '</div>'
  };

  return {
      restrict: 'E'
    , transclude: true
    , replace: true
    , template: function (tElement, tAttrs) {
        return getTemplate(tElement, tAttrs);
    }
  }
});
```

and I compile into my page by using the following mark-up

```
<bdb-toggle-slideable state="expanded">
  <h4>Documentation</h4>
</bdb-toggle-slideable>
<bdb-slideable state="expanded" ng-init="expanded=true" duration="0.3">
  ...
  element content
  ...
</bdb-slideable>
```

there is an extra node wrapped around the toggle element in the mark-up that this generates and an extra attribute, but its close to what I was looking to produce.

```
<div class="toggle" ng-click="expanded=!expanded" state="expanded">
  <ng-transclude>
    <h4 class="ng-scope">Documentation</h4>
  </ng-transclude>
  <span ng-class="{'fa fa-caret-down':!expanded,'fa fa-caret-up':expanded}" class="fa fa-caret-up"></span>
</div>
```

I still have to make sure that the state="" attributes are the same on both the toggle and the slideable elements and that they are unique in the scope of, but as its slightly less code to manage and the internal toggle state and caret line up without manual intervention, its better than what I had.

It is not, of course, exactly what I wanted to achieve, but it works.